# Is it dangerous to not replace a steam boiler pressure gauge that is stuck at 0?

Tags: boiler, steam

Everything else works and it's heating fine. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: The gauge was put there for a reason, right?

Comment: Normally there are block valves to allow isolation and repair/replacement of boiler appurtenances. My presumption is that there is either no valve to isolate the gauge or there is a defective valve, and you are asking due to impracticality of shutting down the unit for gauge replacement?

Comment: Yes. My boiler expert says there are a lot of safety measures to prevent a boiler explosion and you should wait to replace it until the end of the season or if it isn't working right.

Answer (score 3):

Dangerous? If it malfunctions and an over-pressure event occurs, that's dangerous. Whether or not a functioning gauge will provide early warning or not would depend on the experience/knowledge level of the gauge reader and the nature of the malfunction.

Are you required to have a functioning pressure gauge? Most likely you are but it may depend on the duty rating (BTU), type of occupancy, and where you live. Some boilers in some states require regular documented inspections which include a pressure check. Inquire with your local code enforcement agency, although you may not like what you find out about responsibilities attached to steam boiler operators.

But the rules are written in somebody's blood, just do an internet search for boiler explosions and you will see.